# Linked list in c returns negative number instead of adding node

Tags: c, linked-list

Can someone explain to me why this code returns a random negative number instead of adding the node as it should? If the call to addnode is removed the main function works as it should so the problem lies with the addnode function. I don't think it's malloc that has the problem and I can't for the life of me figure out what is. Please help, I'm an amateur at c and I have a vague understanding of how pointers work so I guess something's wrong with my pointers. Here's the full code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int addNode(struct node **head, int value);
void printList(struct node **head);

int main()
{
    int value;
    
    struct node *head;
    head=NULL;
    //int isempty(struct node *head);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    printf("\nInsert node value :");
    scanf("%d",&value);
    addNode(&head,value);
    }
    printList(&head);
     return 0;
}
int addNode(struct node **head,int value)
    {
    struct node *newnode;
    newnode=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    //if(newnode==NULL)
    if(!newnode)
    {
    printf("Memory allocation error \n"); 
    exit(0);
    }
    
    if(*head=NULL)
    {
        newnode->data=value;
        newnode->next=NULL;
        *head=newnode;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        
        struct node *current;
        *current = **head;
        while(current != NULL)
        {
            if(value<=(current->data)){
                //περίπτωση 1ου κόμβου σε μη κενή λίστα
                if(current==*head){
                    newnode->data=value;
                    newnode->next=*head;
                    *head=newnode;
                    return 1;
                }
                //περίπτωση ενδιάμεσου κόμβου
                newnode->data=value;
                return 1;
            }
            current = current->next;
        }

    }
}
/*int isempty(struct node *head){
    return (head==NULL);
}*/

void printList(struct node **head) {
   struct node *ptr = *head;
   printf("\n[ ");
    
   //start from the beginning
   while(ptr != NULL) {
      printf("(%d) ",ptr->data);
      ptr = ptr->next;
   }
   printf(" ]");
   return;
}
```

Comment: `*current = **head;` doesn't look right to me.

Comment: Indeed, turning it into current=*head makes the main work correctly but printlist just prints : []. I guess addnode still doesn't save any nodes, maybe I also messed up the string between the nodes ? Thanks for helping me

Comment: Note: your insert function uses about 30 lines and 2 variables. It can be compacted to about 10 lines and 1 variable, increasing readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for starters you are having an assignment instead of a comparison in addNode

`if(*head=NULL) should be if(*head==NULL)`

Other than that, I think you are trying to maintain the elements in a sorted manner? But in any case you are manipulating pointers a bit more than you need to.

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot to mention the list is supposed to be descending. I completely missed the ==, thanks for that. Now it prints just the first node but I guess I can at least now understand where I might have gone wrong. Thanks for the help !

Comment: Some tweaking and the function now works as inteded. Thanks to you and mr Harvey for the help, you're life savers I have to deliver the project by Thursday and I'd been stuck for weeks !